# Javascript on executing in order despite no asynchronous functions being run

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am running a small function to create a graph using d3, and I am attempting to populate an array with numbers 0-5 in increments of 0.2 (so 0, 0.2, 0.4, etc up to 5). I can't just create a variable equal to 0 and add 0.2 every time because javascript would make the values something like [0, 0.2, 0.2999999999999999999, etc] with messed up numbers. So I have to use the toFixed() method which operates on a number object. In my ocde, I declare a variable that equals 0 and then initiate a for loop and attempt to use the toFixed function on the number in the beginning of the loop. Firebug then tells me that num.toFixed isnt a function - and I realize it is because my for loop (initiated after num's declaration] is executing before num is declared. How do I force javascript to run the for loop after it picks up on my variable declaration?

Here is my function:

```
function createGraph(stall, ovl, swda)
{
var svg = d3.select("#infoGraph").append("svg");

svg.attr("width", 604).attr("height", 500);
svg.append("line").attr("x1", 104).attr("y1", 4).attr("x2", 104).attr("y2", 404).attr("stroke", "black");
svg.append("line").attr("x1", 104).attr("y1", 404).attr("x2", 504).attr("y2", 404).attr("stroke", "black");
svg.append("rect").attr("x", 125).attr("y", (404-(stall)*100)).attr("width", 75).attr("height", (stall*100)).attr("fill", "orange").attr("opacity", 0.5);
svg.append("rect").attr("x", 250).attr("y", (404-(ovl)*100)).attr("width", 75).attr("height", (ovl*100)).attr("fill", "orange").attr("opacity", 0.5);
svg.append("rect").attr("x", 375).attr("y", (404-(swda)*100)).attr("width", 75).attr("height", (swda*100)).attr("fill", "orange").attr("opacity", 0.5);

    //ISSUE OCCURS HERE
var dataset = [];
var legendValue = 10;
var tempVal;
console.log("Before for loop"); //this shows up after my console.log statement within the for loop in firebug's web console.
for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    tempVal = legendValue.toFixed(1); //I get an error here
    legendValue = tempVal;
    dataset.push(legendValue);
    console.log(legendValue);

}
}
```

main code body! - function declared at bottom

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("Script ran");
//d3.select("body").append("p").text("D3 Tests Inbound");
w = 500;
h = 50;

var dataset = [];
for(i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    var randomNum=Math.random() * 30;
    var roundedNum = Math.round(randomNum);
    dataset.push(randomNum);
}

var dataset2 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

d3.select("#randomGraph")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .style("height", function(d){
        var barHeight = 5*d;
        return barHeight + "px"
    })
    .style("margin", "5px");

    var svg = d3.select("#svgGraph").append("svg");
    svg.attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset2)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    circles.attr("cx", function(d, i){
        return (i*50)+25;
    })
    .attr("cy", h/2)
    .attr("r", function(d){
        return d;
    });

    var stall, ovl, swda;
    stall = 3.3;
    ovl = 0.8;
    swda = 3;

    createGraph(3.3, 0.8, 3);

});
```

Firebug output:

[13:04:19.214] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped.

[13:04:19.220] TypeError: legendValue.toFixed is not a function

[13:04:19.220] Before for loop

[13:04:19.220] 10.0

Comment: Where do you declare the function?

Comment: that doesn't seem right... tall this code is contained inside a function, should be executed synchronously.

Comment: I will post the main body of my javascript - the function is called at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LegendValue` is a number prior to the first time through the loop, then in the loop you change it to a string: `legendValue = "" + tempVal + "";`. Once it is a string the `.toFixed` function is no longer a valid option.

[jsfiddle attached](http://jsfiddle.net/N8C7s/1/) to demonstrate with `typeof`

[second jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8C7s/3/) attached to demonstrate working with full code. Graph looks a little funny, but it is working. Note that I'm not assigning a string value to `legendValue` in the loop, but pushing the string `tempVal` onto dataset.

Comment: I have updated the function and removed the portion of code that transforms legendValue into a string. I still recieved the "legendValue.toFixed is not a funtion" error in firebug before my console.log statement that prints "before loop". I will update the code in the question to reflect this change. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because `.toFixed(1)` results in a string the statement `tempVal = legendValue.toFixed(1);` takes the number in legendValue and assigns a string to tempVal. tempVal being a string you then change legendValue to a string when you execute `legendValue = tempVal;` Removing the quotes didn't change the problem you were having. You are still encountering the problem that the first time into the loop you have a number in legendValue, and that in that first time through the loop you change it to a string.